# calculating probability of profit in option trading.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, correlation

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9GQw.jpg) 
This is a reference I took from tastytrade to calculate probability of profit for various strategies but if I try to stimulate the same on my local system the values does not matches the probability of profit in Sensibull or Opstra (strategy builders used for reference).

Also is there any correlation between **option greeks and probability of profit ?**

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @AnotherUser.  Also, I do not understand what you are asking.  If a another MathSE reviewer is able to help you, then fine.  If not, please try to overhaul your posting so that it is impossible for anyone to be confused about the exact nature of the explicit Math problem that you are trying to tackle.